# How can I tell from my Application whether it was started from my BroadcastReceiver or not?

Tags: android

How can I tell from my Application whether it was started/resumed from my BroadcastReceiver or not?

I intercept outgoing calls (`android.intent.action.NEW_OUTGOING_CALL`).  If `getString(Intent.EXTRA_PHONE_NUMBER)` is one of a set of numbers, I abort that call (setResultData(null)) and instead `startActivity` my app, `putExtra`ing the particular number.  If (and only if) coming from the BroadcastReceiver, I want to be able to put up an alert that's basically "use this app with this number/return to call".  However, sometimes when I return to the app from elsewhere, the number still seems to be in the extras of the intent, even though I haven't come from the BroadcastReceiver.  I tried checking for the `FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag, but it shows up sometimes when not coming from the BroadcastReceiver.

Comment: Do you want the user to go back to your activity after the phone call? if the user did make the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you said: you can pass any parameters to your activity, indicating that it was called from your `BroadcastReceiver`. However, when resuming to your activity some code might be executed again - potentially causing unwanted outcomes. When I had once a similar issue I stored/*overwrote* some information in the intent, e.g.

```
myActivity.getIntent().putExtra("phoneNumber", "nil");
```

What worked for me was, that I overwrote the extra in the intent after it has been processed while finishing an `ActionMode` (let's say with `"nil"`). So later I was able to evaluate that information in `onResume()`, e.g.:

```
@Override
public void onResume() {
    super.onResume();

    String phoneNumber = getIntent().getExtras().getString("phoneNumber")

    if ("nil".equals(PhoneNumber)) {
      ...
    }
}
```

Just did a small test and it works pretty well.

Hope this helps ... Cheers!